# Access "this" object in FunScript?

Tags: javascript, f#, funscript

How do I acess the "this" object in FunScript?

For example:

```fs
let this = // ????
Globals.Dollar.Invoke(this).addClass("active")
```

Comment: very bad idea to have such var.....!

Comment: @Jai, Won't this die ?

Comment: Why the downvote? I realize that keeping "this" around would be bad, but the "$(this)" pattern is very common when working with jQuery (with event handlers for example), how do I accomplish the same with FunScript?

Comment: Using the tree and forest analogy, instead of asking a question about a tree maybe you should ask a question about the forest. In other words your question in the comment `the "$(this)" pattern is very common when working with jQuery (with event handlers for example), how do I accomplish the same with FunScript?` is higher level. I don't know the answer. Also if you are just learning F# it is not uncommon to paste in code of one language and show what you have tried and failed using and then ask how to do the same in idiomatic F#. We didn't see what you tried.